# Create a Lightning Web Component to use in Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, community-builder

I am new to Salesforce Communities and started creating one with **Build Your Own** template.

I need to add a list view for Account objects. I can not use the built in list view since there is a logic behind filtering and list view items should be in different colours according to some of its fields. So that I can create a custom list view with Lightning Web Components. Then, I need to add the custom list view to salesforce community. Is that possible? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change Meta file of the component to use in Lightning Community.

You Have to set the target for that.

Here is the example

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Hello World</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="string" type="String" default="jsMetaValue"></property>
            <property name="boolean" type="Boolean" default="true"></property>
            <property name="integer" type="Integer" default="5"></property>
            <property name="picklist" type="String" default="value3" datasource="value1,value2,value3" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I have edited my question such that it is more specialised. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make some changes to **js-meta.xml** file.

In targets tag, you need to mention where all you need to expose your LWC.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="consumerBureau">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: I have edited my question such that it is more specialised. Please have a look.